# Casperjs won't allow using external modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, phantomjs, casperjs

I tried to figure out a memory leak issue in Phantom.js / Casper.js script and found this link

[Detect node.js/javascript memory leak in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723532/detect-node-js-javascript-memory-leak-in-code)

The idea is to include heapdump module

https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-heapdump

But when I run `casperjs myapp.js` and it gave error that it cannot find this heapdump lib even though I installed it.

`var heapdump = require('heapdump');`

Is **casperjs** different from **nodejs**?

Answer (score 3):

CasperJS works with PhantomJS which is node-independent. Although you can install certain node  modules (like underscore) it just won't work out of the box. If you want to use CasperJS with Node.js try [SpookyJS](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS).

Some links that might help you -

http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/writing_modules.html
http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/faq.html

Comment: I remember I tried Spooky last and this was the issue since I run Windows "Spooky's stdio transport reportedly does not work on Windows and Ubuntu."

Comment: Here is the latest issue on Windows https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS/issues/71

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found a work around. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21246476/394811

**`./proxies/underscore.js:`**

```
module.exports = require('underscore');
```

**`./tests/test.js`**

```
var _ = require('../proxies/underscore');
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. --includes=foo.js,bar.js will include the foo.js and bar.js files before each test file execution.