# Can't require Underscore with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using `CasperJS` to run automated frontend tests but have run in to an issue with using other npm modules in my tests. I'm aware of `patchRequire` however I believe that is only to be called outside of the test environment as the test runner patches require automatically. I did include it but the results were the same. It says it can't find the module. I have confirmed the underscore module is installed in `node_modules` in the projects root folder.

**Code**

```
'use strict'

_ = require 'underscore'

testConfig =
    testPageUrl: ''
    testSearchTerm: 'the'

config = _.extend testConfig, require 'common/config'
```

**Code in Javascript**

```
'use strict';

_ = require('underscore');

testConfig = {
  testPageUrl: '',
  testSearchTerm: 'the'
};

config = _.extend(testConfig, require('common/config'));
```

**Error**

> CasperError: Can't find module underscore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So solution I eventually found was to create proxy modules that import the npm module and export it out to the casper script.

**`./proxies/underscore.js:`**

```
module.exports = require('underscore');
```

**`./tests/test.js`**

```
var _ = require('../proxies/underscore');
```