# Logging frameworks for CasperJS

Tags: casperjs, winston, bunyan

Is there a way to use `winston` or `bunyan` with CasperJS ? I couldn't get either to load correctly.

I tried the proxy method described in [Can't require Underscore with CasperJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690968/cant-require-underscore-with-casperjs), but that also didn't work.

Comment: No... possible duplicate of [Use a node module from casperjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387854/use-a-node-module-from-casperjs)

Comment: I browsed through winston and bunyan sources. You could try to rewrite the whole thing to use PhantomJS modules, but this will be likely very complex in comparison to just writing your own logging module.

Comment: `patchRequire(...)` doesn't work. Seems like i'll have to whip up a custom logging solution for my case!