# How to reduce react app build time and understanding behaviour of webpack when bundling

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading, heap-memory, build-time

Recently I am trying to optimize the performance of a web app(React). Assuming it is somewhat heavy as it consists of Code editors, Firebase, SQL, AWS SDK, etc. So I integrated [react-loadable](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable#readme) which will lazy load the components, After that, I got this Javascript heap out of memory issue.

`FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory in React`

After some research(From a friend), I came to know that If we keep too many lazy loadings webpack will try to bundle them parallelly It might be the cause to get a Javascript heap memory issue, To confirm that I removed all Lazy loading routes in my App and built. Now build is successful. Later as suggested by the community I increased Node heap space size and got the below insights

First I increased it to **8 GB(8192)** then build is success I got build time of around **72 mins**, From next time onwards I am getting around **20 mins**. Then I decreased heap memory size to **4 GB(4096)** and getting build success it is around **15 - 20 mins**. System configuration is **2vCPU, 16GB RAM(AWS EC2 Instance `r5a.large`)**.

Next, I kept build in another system (**Mac book pro, i5, 8 GB RAM, 4 Cores**) Now it took **30 mins**, Second time it took **20 mins**

So from these data points, I got a couple of questions

1. Do we need to keep increasing heap space whenever we add some code? If yes what would be the average heap memory size in the community
2. What would be the usual configuration for build systems for these kinds of heavy apps, Why because now I am not sure whether to increase the number of cores or RAM or Heap space or Altogether something to do with our app code.
3. Do webpack provide any kind of solutions to avoid heap memory issue like limiting parallel processes, or any plugins?
4. If at all it is related with our App code, Is there any standard process to debug where it is taking memory and to optimize based on that

**PS** : Some people suggested to keep `GENERATE_SOUCREMAP=false` it got worked but we need source maps as they will be helpful in debugging production issues

Comment: Good grief. That seems outrageous.  Here we worry that end user usability is compromised if a web page takes more than half a second to load.  But we tolerate build times that take not just minutes but tens of minutes?  Whatever happened to developer usability? How can this be considered an improvement over web development before frameworks when compile time was instant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I could resolve the `heap out of memory` issue without increasing heap memory space.

As mentioned in the question If I remove all Lazy routes build is getting successful Or I had to keep 4GB Heap space to get it success with plenty of build time. When the build is success with 4GB Heapspace I observed that nearly 8 - 10 chunk files sizes are nearly 1MB. So I analyzed all those chunks using [Source map explorer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer). In all chunks almost same libraries code is included (In my case those are Firebase, Video player, etc which are heavy)

So In my assumption when webpack is trying to bundle all these chunks It had to build all those libraries dependency graph in every chunk which in turn causes heap memory space issue. So I used [Loadable components](https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components) to lazy load those libraries.

After lazy loading all those libraries all chunks files size is reduced almost by half, And Build is getting success without increasing any heap space and build time also got reduced.

After optimization if I keep build in **6vCPU , i7 System** it is taking around **3 - 4 minutes** and I observed that based on the number of Cores available in the system build time is getting reduced. If I keep build in 2vCPU system it is taking around 20 - 25 mins like that sometimes

Comment: If you want a "modular" build of many parts that can dynamically load other parts of it, rather than a monolithic build, you want to use `webpack-module-federation`. It can further improve things, since it allows you to easily share dependencies between multiple packages or other individual parts of your build. Its documentation currently is still sparse, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67755898/2228771) is a good getting started guide.

Comment: If you are still interested, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66473378/memory-leaks-in-node-js-how-to-analyze-allocation-tree-roots/66563755#66563755) is how to debug heap allocations in Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla webpack has been developed for monolithic builds. It's main purpose is to take many modules and bundle them into ONE (not many). If you want to keep things modular, you want to use `webpack-module-federation` (`WMF`):

1. `WMF` allows you to develop independent packages that can easily depend on (and lazy load) each other.
2. These packages will automatically share dependencies between each other.

Without WMF, webpack allows none of the above.

### Short Example

1. A library package `app2` provides a component `Button`
2. An application package `app1` consumes it.
3. When the time comes, `app1` requests a component using dynamic `import`.
4. You can wrap the load using [React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy), like so:

   ```js
   const RemoteButton = React.lazy(() => import("app2/Button"));
   ```

   - E.g., you can do this in a `useEffect`, or a `Route.render` callback etc.
5. `app1` can use that component, once it's loaded. While loading, you might want to show a loading screen (e.g. using `Suspense`):

   ```js
   <React.Suspense fallback={<LoadingScreen />}>
     <RemoteButton />
   </React.Suspense>
   ```

- Alternatively, instead of using `lazy` and `Suspense`, just take the promise returned from the `import(...)` statement and handle the asynchronous loading any way you prefer. Of course, `WMF` is not at all restricted to `react` and can load any module dynamically.

On the flip side, `WMF` dynamic loading must use dynamic `import` (i.e. `import(...)`), because:

1. non-dynamic imports will always resolve at load time (thus making it a non-dynamic dependency), and
2. "dynamic `require`" cannot be bundled by webpack since browsers have no concept of `commonjs` (unless you use some hacks, in which case, you will lose the relevant "loading `promise`").

### Documentation

Even though, in my experience, `WMF` is mature, easy to use, and probably production ready, [it's official documentation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/) is currently only a not all too polished collection of conceptual notes. That is why I would recommend [this as a "Getting Started" guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67755898/2228771).