# Hyperapp / Webpack - How to code split component

Tags: webpack, code-splitting, hyperapp

To reduce the initial load of my app, i try to do code splitting.
For exemple, i successfully split twilio-video, to load and initialize when user press "call"

```
import('twilio-video').then(Video => {
    Video.connect(twilioInfo.data.token, options).then(room => {
        ...
    });
});
```

Webpack correctly split the code and load it when needed.

Now i would like to do the same with components, or routes (to not load user profil while we stand on login page).
Is there any equivalent of

```
const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));
```

or

```
const Home = lazy(() => import('./routes/Home'));
```

or any other way to load component when a route path is hitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It used to be very difficult. These days, [Webpack Module Federation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/) makes it a breathe.

They have [tons of samples](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/) to get you started. For example, [the basic-host-remote sample](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/blob/master/basic-host-remote/) has a simple scenario that fits your need. Just fetch the entire Github repo, `cd` into this sample, and run it (as explained in each sample's `README`).

Keep an eye open for the Network tab. Components are not loaded until they are explicitely requested.

### Basic Example

[The basic-host-remote sample](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/blob/master/basic-host-remote/) has two separate packages: `app1` and `app2`.

1. `app1` wants to use components from `app2`

   - It adds `app2` to its `remotes` in [its WMF config](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/blob/master/basic-host-remote/app1/webpack.config.js#L39)
2. `app2` provides a [`Button`](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/blob/master/basic-host-remote/app2/src/Button.js) component

   - `app2` `exposes` `Button` in [its WMF config](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/blob/master/basic-host-remote/app2/webpack.config.js#L32).
3. [app1/src/App.js](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/blob/master/basic-host-remote/app1/src/App.js) loads the button dynamically. (It does so during initial render, making the on-demand loading a lot less obvious.)
4. When the time comes, `app1` requests a component using dynamic `import`.
5. It wraps the load using [React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy), like so:

   ```js
   const RemoteButton = React.lazy(() => import("app2/Button"));
   ```

   - E.g., you can do this in a `useEffect`, or a `Route.render` callback etc.
6. `app1` can use that `Button`, once it's loaded. While loading, it shows a loading message, using `Suspense`:

   ```js
   <React.Suspense fallback={<LoadingScreen />}>
     <RemoteButton />
   </React.Suspense>
   ```

   - Alternatively, instead of using `lazy` and `Suspense`, you can just take the promise returned from the `import(...)` statement and handle the asynchronous loading any way you prefer. Of course, `WMF` is not at all restricted to `react` and can load any module dynamically.
   - Note that both, `app1` and `app2` have the same `shared` setup, making sure that those shared dependencies are only loaded one time, and not bundled/duplicated with remotely loaded code:

   ```js
   {
     // ...
     shared: { react: { singleton: true }, "react-dom": { singleton: true } },
   }
   ```

Note that `WMF` dynamic loading must use dynamic `import` (i.e. `import(...)`), because:

1. non-dynamic imports will always resolve at load time (thus making it a non-dynamic dependency), and
2. "dynamic `require`" cannot be bundled by webpack since browsers have no concept of `commonjs` (unless you use some hacks, in which case, you will lose the relevant "loading `promise`").

## WMF Samples

WMF takes a bit of learning, but all its samples have the following common elements:

1. Every sample has multiple independent packages.
2. Each package has its own `webpack.config.js`
3. Each package usually acts as a host (which provides components dynamically) or a consumer of such components, or both.
4. In `development` mode, you usually serve up everything using the nicely integrated `webpack-dev-server`.

   - NOTE: In `production` mode, you want to make some small adjustments to your config. When `webpack-dev-server` is out of the picture, your build just adds some additional `remoteEntry.js` files to your build output.
5. You can easily configure what to do with common dependencies, using the `shared` configuration. (Usually you want them to act as singletons, meaning, everyone should share common dependencies, and not pack their own.)
6. If you want to insist on keeping everything in one package, that is probably also possible. Just `expose` it and add its own (independent) components to its own `remotes`. Not sure if it works, but its worth trying.

## Final Words

Again, it will take a bit of a learning curve, but I find it's definitely worth it. Feels like one of the most sophisticated dynamic build + load systems I have seen.

Most annoyingly, WMF still does not currently have proper API documentation on the Webpack page, but I'm sure it'll come soon enough. Currently, there is only a not all too polished [collection of conceptual notes](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/).

The WMF author himself [promises to provide better documentation soon](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation.github.io/issues/20#issuecomment-858281762)™️.

Luckily, for learning, [the samples](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/) are really good, actively maintained and still being enhanced.